# Swagger(2.0) Editor two different body for same endpoint

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

Our platform supports only Swagger 2.0 version.
For one Endpoint, I use two different bodies for two situations. Based on the body parameter, it will pass onto if-else. Both bodies have some fields in common

I tried to append `#1` and `#2` at end of endpoint. But it doesnt work. Is there any other workaround

I tried two bodies and Swagger validation fails.

```
paths:
  /v1/endpoint:
    post:
      operationId: api.handle_endpoint
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body [a]
          description: a
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/a'
        - in: body
          name: body[b]
          description: To a
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/b'
```

Is there any workaround for this in Swagger 2.0?

Comment: Are A and B bodies completely different, or do they share at least some common fields?

Comment: @Helen Yeah they have some common fields